# JS IntelliSense and suggestions not working correctly with node js and express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS Code with Node JS and Express JS development about the IntelliSense and code suggestions.

Given this simple example:

```
const expressHandlebars = require("express-handlebars");

app.engine("handlebars", expressHandlebars({}));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.set("views", "views/handlebars/pages");
```

When I'm trying to add a configuration inside the `expressHandlebars({})` function parameter, there is nothing related to this appears to me.

But when I go inside the function implementation I got this:

```
function ExpressHandlebars(config) {
    // Config properties with defaults.
    utils.assign(this, {
        handlebars     : Handlebars,
        extname        : '.handlebars',
        layoutsDir     : undefined, // Default layouts directory is relative to `express settings.view` + `layouts/`
        partialsDir    : undefined, // Default partials directory is relative to `express settings.view` + `partials/`
        defaultLayout  : undefined,
        helpers        : undefined,
        compilerOptions: undefined,
    }, config);

    // Express view engine integration point.
    this.engine = this.renderView.bind(this);

    // Normalize `extname`.
    if (this.extname.charAt(0) !== '.') {
        this.extname = '.' + this.extname;
    }

    // Internal caches of compiled and precompiled templates.
    this.compiled    = Object.create(null);
    this.precompiled = Object.create(null);

    // Private internal file system cache.
    this._fsCache = Object.create(null);
}
```

So there are about 7 items I can pass in the config object.

How can I fix that?

Just a note: I added a `jsconfig.json` file in the root of my project as the documentation said and this is the content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Does the suggestions show up if you type `Ctrl + Space`?

Comment: @RobinThomas I'm using MacOS, and no, nothing is shown when pressing `Ctrl + Space`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're supposed to be writing something like either of the following depending on what module system your project is using:

```js
// ES Modules
import { ExpressHandlebars } from "express-handlebars";
new ExpressHandlebars({
   // trigger suggestions here
});
```

```js
// CommonJS
const expressHandlebars = require("express-handlebars");
expressHandlebars.create({
   // trigger suggestions here
});
```